# java.sql.sqlexception ora-00904 invalid identifier in oracle 10 g

Tags: jakarta-ee

```
ps=con.prepareStatement("update customer set  customerId=?,customerName =?,Add1=? where customerd="+str1);

ps.setString(1,str1);
ps.setString(2,str2);
ps.setString(3,str3);

int j=ps.executeUpdate();
```

i am getting this Error.while submitting these code.

Answer (score 2):

if you read the query carefully, you'll see that you have a typo in `customerd` (missing I). I would suggest you to run any query on a database client before putting it in your code, to figure our these types of simple errors.

Also the value in the `where` condition probably needs to be between single quotes, which again, you can test if you run the query outside java, in the database client.

Answer (score 1):

Does it help you?

Otherwise try to do this one:

```
update customer set  customerId=?,customerName ='?',Add1='?' where customerd= '"+str1+"'"
```

i.e add extra ' ' near your str1 and ?.

Hope that will help you!